# using stash variable with same name like EE var

Tags: stash, variable, template-partials, duplicate

loping through channel entries tag, I can use {title} for the title of the article.

inside the channel entries loop for the specific article,  I use an EE partial with get list inside. Inside the list I have a stash var called "title".

```
{stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
```

While using the EE partial, {title} always prints the title of the actual channel entry. While using it not as EE partial, but as an EE embed, the var {title} is choosen from the stash list.

**code:**

```
//stash embed which creates the list with related entries
{exp:stash:embed:ech:stash_related_entries stash:entry_id="{entry_id}"}

{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment:entry}" dynamic="off"}
   //display the detail article

   //show related article inside the body of the article
   {s_showRelatedEntries}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**code EE partial:**

```
    {exp:stash:parse process="end"}
        {exp:stash:get_list name="dataRelated"}
            {title}
            //HERE prints the title of the detail entry
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    {/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Can't quite follow the explanation, but have you tried using a stash prefix  for the stash variables when you get:list? https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#examples